Adding VichUploaderBundle to bundles.php causes UuidGenerator Problem
I've been trying to find out what the problem is for the past few hours and I am still at a loss. I've added VichUploaderBundle to my Symfony 6 project as instructed in the installation.md
vich_uploader:
    db_driver: orm

but I get this error:

Context: Using the database to generate a UUID through Doctrine\ORM\Id\UuidGenerator
Problem: Feature was deprecated in doctrine/dbal 2.x and is not supported by installed doctrine/dbal:3.x
Solution: See the doctrine/deprecations logs for new alternative approaches.

I've looked the error up but I don't think the results I've found were relevant to me. I checked the code and I don't seem to be using anything related to UUID generation so far. I just find it strange that it only shows up when I have VichUploaderBundle enabled.
